# RxSwift MVVM State

Tags: swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I'm using `RxSwift` with `MVVM`. I have a situation where I load a screen of questions. Each is represented by a `QuestionViewModel`, containing the question and the `questionAnswer` as `Drivers`. The problem I have is I want to save the answers from the `QuestionViewModels` but only when they press Save button on the main screen. Its easy enough to subscribe to when a question is individually answered but this will do each as pressed, instead I want in one batch on save, as they could press back and want to cancel.

```
struct ClientProfileViewModel { 
    private let service: Service
    private let client: Client?

    let questionnaire: Observable<Questionnaire>
    let answerViewModels: Observable<[QuestionViewModel]>

    init(service: Service, client: Client?) {
        self.service = service
        self.client = client

        self.questionnaire = self.service.questionnaire(client: client)

        self.answerViewModels = self.questionnaire.map { (questionnaire) -> [QuestionViewModel] in
            return questionnaire.questions.map { question in
                let answer = client?.answers.first(where: { (qa) -> Bool in
                    return qa.question.questionId == question.questionId
                }) ?? QuestionAnswer(question: question, answerYesNo: nil, answerText: nil)

                return QuestionViewModel(question: question, answer: answer)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct QuestionViewModel {
    private let question: Question
    private let answer: QuestionAnswer

    let questionOutput: Driver<Question>
    let answerOutput: Driver<QuestionAnswer>


    init(question: Question, answer: QuestionAnswer) {
        self.question = question
        self.answer = answer

        self.questionOutput = BehaviorRelay<Question>(value: self.question).asDriver()
        self.answerOutput = BehaviorRelay<QuestionAnswer>(value: self.answer).asDriver()
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you share how you set value to `questionAnswer`?

Comment: Have updated how I create the view model. In terms of updating, I'm not sure how best. I did wonder if I need to use Replay() so I send update updates and then when do the save I replay all...

Comment: `QuestionViewModel` created in moment when user answer the question, right?

Comment: Have updated code slightly, the QuestionViewModel is what I use to bind to tableview. There is a view inside the cell which fires an rx event when answered, how to channel that answer to save as batch event is my issue. I wonder if letting it fire every time is the correct way, and then use replay later on